# How to add leading zeros for for-loop in shell?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a basic number for loop which increments the variable num by 1 over each iteration...

```
for (( num=1; num<=5; num++ ))
do
 echo $num
done
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm trying to make it produce the output (add leading zero before $num):

```
01
02
03
04
05
```

Without doing:

```
echo 0$num
```

Comment: Use `printf` with an appropriate format.

Comment: printf from bash has many bad effect, i prefer use awk as following: "num=$(echo $num | awk '{printf("%02d", $1)}'"

Comment: @binogure Just a heads up: Awk has different behavior on different systems. There's mawk, gawk, awk, nawk, etc. I try not to recommend it because it seems like I can only test it on the computer I'm writing it on. Perl/Ruby are more compatible.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' {01..05}`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18469460/188159 should be set as the answer.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Note: The `{01..05}` syntax will work only in Bash >=4.x, not in <=3.x.

Comment: for n in echo {0..2}{0..9}; do echo $n;done

Answer (score 407, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
$ for i in {01..05}; do echo "$i"; done
01
02
03
04
05
```

Disclaimer: Leading zeros only work in `>=bash-4`.

If you want to use `printf`, nothing prevents you from putting its result in a variable for further use:

```
$ foo=$(printf "%02d" 5)
$ echo "${foo}"
05
```

Comment: Best answer, and it avoids using clumsy external commands (like 'seq', not necessary in proper Bash). Helped me.

Comment: Unfortunately the {01..05} doesn't work for older versions of bash. I'm on a server with bash 3.2.51 and that will print the numbers without leading zeroes. On my desktop with 4.2.37 it does work well though.

Comment: @thomanski Fair point, the [Changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) states that this feature got introduced with `bash-4.0-alpha`: *Brace expansion now allows zero-padding of expanded numeric values and will add the proper number of zeroes to make sure all values contain he same number of digits.)*.

Comment: doesn't work for e.g. {01..10} though

Comment: @Matt What exactly does not work? As long as you have a recent enough version of `bash` this works fine.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! Here is my version: `for i in \`seq 1 1 50\`; echo $(printf "%02d" $i); done`, which will output `01 02 ... 50`.

Comment: @SRG `seq` can do the padding itself if you want to pad to the widest numbers width using `-w`, besides that your example is invalid as it misses the `do`. Here is how you can do it: `for i in \`seq -w 1 50\`; do echo $i; done`

Comment: @Vampire I cannot edit my comment to fix the missing `do`, but thanks for the alternative, sounds interesting!

Comment: m=4;printf -v m "%02d" $m;echo $m

Answer (score 82):

`seq -w` will detect the max input width and normalize the width of the output.

```
for num in $(seq -w 01 05); do
    ...
done
```

At time of writing this didn't work on the newest versions of OSX, so you can either install macports and use its version of `seq`, or you can set the format explicitly:

```
seq -f '%02g' 1 3
    01
    02
    03
```

But given the ugliness of format specifications for such a simple problem, I prefer the solution Henk and Adrian gave, which just uses Bash. Apple can't screw this up since there's no generic "unix" version of Bash:

```
echo {01..05}
```

Or:

```
for number in {01..05}; do ...; done
```

Comment: Just fyi `seq` is not present on OSX

Comment: It's on my machine (OS X 10.7.5). The man page only dates to 2010, so it looks to be a (relatively) recent addition.

Comment: doesnt work on mac os sierra for 01 to 05. but works for 01 to 10.

Comment: Try giving seq a format string.

`seq -f '%02g' 1 5`

Comment: @blarf I mentioned that in the middle of my answer, but I'm generally opposed to format strings for very simple formats like this.

Comment: `seq -w` really does the job without clutter!

Comment: what is the difference between `'%02g'` and `'%02d'` (which are others using plain `printf` are suggesting)?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy According to the docs, `seq` doesn't support `%d`. The format flags seem a bit different than for `printf`. http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html#seq-invocation

Comment: This solution with "seq -f '%02g' 1 3" is very useful when "1 and 3" are unformatted input variables, like  "seq -f '%02g' ${dia_ini} ${dia_fim}"

Comment: The way to go! This should be the accepted answer for really universal padding with zeros (e.g. `-f '%04g'` will properly pad 10 to "0010" and not to "000010").

Comment: I really like the seq option, particularly when the user has to pass conditional variables into a loop that disqualifies the use of brace expansion. The C-style loops can also be used to execute this, but seq feels cleaner to me.

Answer (score 58):

Use `printf` command to have `0` padding:

```
printf "%02d\n" $num
```

Your for loop will be like this:

```
for (( num=1; num<=5; num++ )); do printf "%02d\n" $num; done
01
02
03
04
05
```

Comment: I'm not interested in outputting it to the screen (that's what printf is mainly used for, right?) The variable $num is going to be used as a parameter for another program but let me see what I can do with this.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to do than I can suggest a better suited answer.

Comment: @BruceBlacklaws `printf` in the shell is used for creating strings from a list of arguments. Output to screen is just the default. In fact, shell pipelines are the ultimate example of functional programming -- just input, output, no side-effects. ;-)

Answer (score 31):

> I'm not interested in outputting it to the screen (that's what printf is mainly used for, right?) The variable $num is going to be used as a parameter for another program but let me see what I can do with this.

You can still use `printf`:

```
for num in {1..5}
do
   value=$(printf "%02d" $num)
   ... Use $value for your purposes
done
```

Comment: This works but spawning subshell is expensive. For big sequences it  may take very long time.

Answer (score 14):

From bash 4.0 onward, you can use *Brace Expansion* with fixed length strings.  See below for the original announcement.

It will do just what you need, and does not require anything external to the shell.

```
$ echo {01..05}
01 02 03 04 05

for num in {01..05}
do
  echo $num
done
01
02
03
04
05
```

---

[CHANGES, release bash-4.0, section 3](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)

> This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-4.0 since
> the release of bash-3.2.
>
> . . .
>
> > z.  Brace expansion now allows zero-padding of expanded numeric values and will add the proper number of zeroes to make sure all values contain the same number of digits.

Comment: I know I did not specify which version of BASH and what platform it's running on but this flat fails on GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)

Comment: @BruceBlacklaws Correct.  The fixed length numbers were added in 4.0.  Included the restriction.

Answer (score 11):

why not `printf '%02d' $num`? See `help printf` for this internal bash command.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note:
I have experienced different behaviours on different versions of bash:

- version 3.1.17(1)-release-(x86_64-suse-linux) and
- Version 4.1.17(9)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin))

for the former (3.1) `for nn in (00..99) ; do ...` works but `for nn in (000..999) ; do ...` does not work
both will work on version 4.1 ; haven't tested printf behaviour 
(`bash --version` gave the version info)

Cheers, Jan