# make numerous directories using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to make the following directories using shell script,

```
00, 01, 02, ..., 50
```

I have tried the script as follows:

```
for ((1;i<=${1};i=i+1))
do
mkdir ${i}
done
```

But I get

```
0, 1, 2, ..., 50
```

How to modify the script? thanks.

Comment: printf(1) will help get the number into the appropriate format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add leading zeros for for-loop in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18460123/608639), [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8789729/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 0 50)
do
  mkdir $i
done
```

should do the trick.