# convert metadata value to string while doing ffmpeg conversion

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, metadata

I have a script which splits mp3 files into smaller files and incrementally numbers them.  I'm now also trying to incrementally increase the **-metadata title** number value and **-metadata track** number value but ffmpeg sees everything as a string. The line I'm having issue with is.

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -f segment -segment_time 1200 -ar 22050 -ac 1 -metadata title="$%03d-$fn.mp3" -metadata track="$%02d" "$splitdirname/%03d-$fn.mp3" #split every 20mins
```

If you look at the metadata title created it says **$%03d-title_of_file.mp3** I'm trying to get the metatdata title to increment like *001-title_of_file.mp3*, *002-title_of_file.mp3*, *003-title_of_file.mp3*,...

The full script i'm using is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#run using bash mp3spl.sh
currentdir="$(pwd)" #get current directory


for f in *.mp3 # only look for mp3 files
do

#fn=`echo "$1" | cut -d'.' -f1` #get just the filename no extension
fn=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1) #get just the filename no extension
echo "($fn)"

splitdirname="$currentdir/split-$fn" #sub directory with correct names
#echo "splitdirname $splitdirname"
mkdir -p "$splitdirname" #make split directory
#echo "Processing $f"
ffmpeg -i "$1" 2> tmp.txt

ffmpeg -i "$f" -f segment -segment_time 1200 -ar 22050 -ac 1 -metadata title="$%03d-$fn.mp3" -metadata track="$%02d" "$splitdirname/%03d-$fn.mp3" #split every 20mins

#rm tmp.txt

done
```

**Using -metadata title="$%03d-$fn.mp3" -metadata track="$%02d" does not create incremental numbers with leading zeros when used with ffmpeg.**

Comment: Why are you expecting `$%03d` to be a) filled with a number and b) be incremented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add leading zeros for for-loop in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460123/how-to-add-leading-zeros-for-for-loop-in-shell)

Comment: @slhck %03d-$fn.mp3 will create incremental numbers with leading zeros with ffmpeg but not used within the -metadata tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%03d` syntax is only valid for input or output file patterns, for those (de)muxers that implement this kind of parsing (e.g., `image2`, `segment`). You cannot use it for setting metadata attributes. In other words, you can't have ffmpeg populate the field with the current segment filename.

Also, the `$` in `$%03d` does not make sense—you're not referring to a shell variable here.

If you want to set the metadata according to the filename of the file that is generated, you have to do this in a second pass. Loop over each generated file, parse its filename, and use that to set the metadata value. Copy the existing audio/video streams with `-c copy` and `-map 0` (the latter is necessary if you have more than one audio/video stream).