# Bash script to remove leading zeros in file name

Tags: bash

My task is easy enough to accomplish in python, but I am trying to do it with a Bash script.

I have files named `[0001-9999].jpg` (i.e, always 4 digits long; e.g, `0003.jpg`, `4003.jpg`) in two different directories,
'left' & 'right' (corresponding to left and right-page bindings of a scanned book). I want to combine the two directories, in ascending order such that they are named `[1-19998].jpg` in a new 'output' directory.

**I am stuck at getting my Bash script to recreate the filename format (always 4-digits, ranging from 0001 to 9999) so that I can `cp` them to 'output'.**

Here is what I have so far in `combine.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# combine.sh assumes it is copied into intended directory, and all files are in order and present. 
# verso (left page) folder is called 'left', recto (right page) folder is called 'right'.
# first (and only) argument should be the word 'left' or 'right' in lower-caps, for first page.

# get total number of pages
l=`ls -l left | wc -l`
r=`ls -l right | wc -l`
size=$(( ($l - 1) + ($r - 1) ))

# set $first offset based on input
if [ "$1" == "left" ]
then
    first=0
  elif [ "$1" == "right" ]
then
    first=1
else
    echo invalid first
fi

# loop to copy files
j=1
for (( i=1 ; i<=$size; i++ ));
do
    # alternate between left and right, starting w/ $1
    # copying into ./output/ with new name [i].jpg
    dir=$(( (i + 1 + first) % 2 )) # offset for left or right
    if [ $dir -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo should be 000$j.jpg 
        # move/copy next jpg of verso dir into combined dir
      elif [ $dir -eq 1 ]
    then
        (( j += 1 ))
        # move/copy next jpg of recto dir into combined dir
    fi
done
```

Clearly, my current model wouldn't work past `0009.jpg`. It is the last piece of this script (just need to `cp` after) though, and any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm guessing I need to do some `awk`-ing on the input filename strings?

Comment: Have you tried using `seq`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18460169/5517838

Comment: You want to only have a 4 digit number, but you want to have the final file of the renumbered series be `19998`? Stick with 5 digits for all files, (yes 4 leading zeros for the first ten). The file names will naturally sort and you wont have to go thru any tricks to keep files from presenting as `1.jpg, 11.jpg, 2.jpg, 21.jpg` etc (not a great example, I hope you get the idea, too much typing required (-;!) .

Comment: Also I'd make a copy of theoriginal data safely away from your programming enviroment. One goof will mess up your whole project. AND code like `echo mv $side/$num.jpg merged/$newNum.jpg` so you can verify that your rename project is working correctly. Once you check and recheck that those `mv` are working correctly, then you either redirect the whole output to a shell instance OR you can remove the `echo`. (i.e. `./myFileFixer left right merged | bash`). OR replace the idea of `mv` files, and use `cp` (then you may not need to make a backup, but you will be creating a duplicate set) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thank you for the reminder to use `cp` and backups while testing. i am receiving the files from a scanner device that names the files such that they all have 4 digits, but i would like to get rid of the leading zeros in their combined form. (ie if i could make them all 5 digits, i would, but that is another scripting problem for me to be able to apply across 100s of pages!)

Comment: Using *`perl renmae`*, you could simply: `rename 's/^0*//g' ????.jpg`  ( `apt install rename` ).

Comment: @shellter Something like: `files=(????.jpg);paste -d \  <(printf 'mv %s\n' ${files[@]@Q}) <(printf '"%s"\n' ${files[@]/#*(0)})` then `| sh`,, Work even if filename begin by fixed string: `files=(IMG_????.jpg);paste -d \  <(printf 'mv %s\n' ${files[@]@Q}) <(printf '"%s"\n' "${files[@]/#IMG_*(0)/IMG_}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
case $1 in
left) dir2=right ;;
right) dir2=left ;;
*) # TODO handle bad argument
esac
dir1=$1

n=0
for src1 in "$dir1"/*.jpg; do
  echo mv "$src1" "output/$((n+=1)).jpg"

  src2=$dir2${src1#"$dir1"}
  if test -e "$src2"; then
    echo mv "$src2" "output/$((n+=1)).jpg"
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

Remove `echo`s if the output looks good.

Comment: flawless. could you explain how `src2=$dir2${src1#"$dir1"}` reconfigures the string? of course, i understand that it replaces dir1 with dir2 in the string src1 - but i struggle to follow everything that is happening there.

Comment: @shea `${var#"str"}` removes `str` from the beginning of the value of `var` (if it's there, otherwise it's a no-op); double quotes around `$dir1` are not necessary in this case, but in general they prevent `str` from being interpreted as a shell pattern (if `str` were `*a` for example, it'd remove the shortest prefix that ends with an `a`, i.e `baca` would become `ca`). Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straightforward approach using a `for` loop iterating over the numbers, and `printf` to format them as needed.

- `printf %04d` produces a 4-digit string, left-padding with 0s
- `printf %05d` produces a 5-digit string, left-padding with 0s
- `$((i*2))` produces even numbers by doubling `$i`
- `$((i*2-1))` produces odd numbers by doubling `$i`, then subtracting `1`

```bash
for i in {1..9999}; do
  
  # future odd numbers from the left side
  mv "left/$(printf %04d $i).jpg" "./$(printf %05d $((i*2-1))).jpg"
  
  # future even numbers from the right side
  mv "right/$(printf %04d $i).jpg" "./$(printf %05d $((i*2))).jpg"
  
done
```

This will perform:

```bash
mv "left/0001.jpg" "./00001.jpg"
mv "right/0001.jpg" "./00002.jpg"
mv "left/0002.jpg" "./00003.jpg"
mv "right/0002.jpg" "./00004.jpg"
mv "left/0003.jpg" "./00005.jpg"
mv "right/0003.jpg" "./00006.jpg"
mv "left/0004.jpg" "./00007.jpg"
mv "right/0004.jpg" "./00008.jpg"
mv "left/0005.jpg" "./00009.jpg"
mv "right/0005.jpg" "./00010.jpg"
mv "left/0006.jpg" "./00011.jpg"
mv "right/0006.jpg" "./00012.jpg"
:
mv "left/9997.jpg" "./19993.jpg"
mv "right/9997.jpg" "./19994.jpg"
mv "left/9998.jpg" "./19995.jpg"
mv "right/9998.jpg" "./19996.jpg"
mv "left/9999.jpg" "./19997.jpg"
mv "right/9999.jpg" "./19998.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script doesn't use any non-builtin functions and zero-aligns the output filenames, so they always sort correctly.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LEFTS=(left/*.jpg)
RIGHTS=(right/*.jpg)

if [[ ${#LEFTS[@]} -ne ${#RIGHTS[@]} ]]; then
    printf 'Error: Uneven page counts: left: %d, right: %d\n' \
        "${#LEFTS[@]}" \
        "${#RIGHTS[@]}" \
        >&2
    exit 1
fi
mkdir -p combined

# How many images all together?
TOTAL=$(( ${#LEFTS[@]} + ${#RIGHTS[@]} ))
# E.g. TOTAL = 19998, then ALIGN is 5
ALIGN=${#TOTAL}

OUT_IDX=0
for (( SRC_IDX = 0; SRC_IDX < ${#LEFTS[@]}; ++SRC_IDX )); do
    printf -v OUT_FN_L "combined/%0${ALIGN}d.jpg" "$(( OUT_IDX++ ))"
    printf -v OUT_FN_R "combined/%0${ALIGN}d.jpg" "$(( OUT_IDX++ ))"
    IN_FN_R=${RIGHTS[$SRC_IDX]}
    IN_FN_L=${RIGHTS[$SRC_IDX]}

    ln "$IN_FN_L" "$OUT_FN_L" &&
    ln "$IN_FN_R" "$OUT_FN_R" || exit
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for FILE in `ls`; do mv $FILE `echo $FILE | sed -e 's:^0*::'`; done
```

- `ls` lists your directory
- we loop the results of `ls` as `FILE`
- we move `FILE` to its new name

Comment: this is a cool piece of shell wizardry! would you mind explaining the `s:^0*::`  term a bit so that i might adapt it to my alternating case?

Comment: Some suggestions: `for file` (lower case shell variables), `in *` (don't parse `ls`), `mv "$file"` (quote variables), `"$(…)"` (backticks are outdated), `printf '%s' "$file" | …` (`echo` is unreliable)

Comment: If you aren't experienced with the shell, probably run https://shellcheck.net/ on your code before posting an answer.